# ctorrent error, initial meta info failed

Tags: shell, torrent

I am unable to torrent Udacities self driving car data on my google cloud Linux VM. I have been able to do it on my Windows 10 OS with uTorrent and 7-zip, but not in Linux.

I tried using both ctorrent and rtorrent:

```
$ wget https://github.com/udacity/self-driving-car/blob/master/datasets/CH2/Ch2_002.tar.gz.torrent
$ ctorrent Ch2_002.tar.gz.torrent
error, initial meta info failed.


$ rtorrent Ch2_002.tar.gz.torrent
Reading torrent file failed: "./Ch2_002.tar.gz.torrent"
```

Any info on getting the dataset downloaded to a .tar.gz file on Linux would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's a GitHub problem, not a torrent problem. You downloaded an HTML page. You want https://github.com/udacity/self-driving-car/raw/master/datasets/CH2/Ch2_002.tar.gz.torrent instead.

Comment: aw that was it, thanks!